# PHP array in array in array $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a question about displaying a variable that is in the an array of another array. Below is an example of a `var_dump()` of my `$_POST` variable. As you can see I have an array.. and another array in that array.. and another array in that array.. I actually need a variable from each of the layers.

```
Array(
[type] => note
[date_time] => 17-01-01
[initiated_from] => admin
[initiated_by] => admin
[list] => 0
[note] => THIS IS A TEST 
[contact] => Array
    (
        [id] => 250
        [email] => TEST@TESTING.COM
        [first_name] => TEST
        [last_name] => McTESTER
        [phone] => (777)777-7777
        [ip] => 0.0.0.0
        [tags] => buyer, requote, followup1, delete
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [3] => TESTER@TESTER.com
                [5] => TESTING TESTER
                [10] => STATE
                [11] => CITY
                [12] => COUNTY
                [6] => PHONE NUMBER
                [8] => www.test.com
                [9] =>  MORE TESTS
            )
```

Here is my code that I tried.

```
$sql_note="INSERT INTO customer_notes(customer_email,note,added_by,note_date) VALUES('$_POST[contact][email]','$_POST[note]','$_POST[contact][fields][3]','$note_date')";
```

(Ignore the `$note_date`)  So these are the three things I am trying to get..

```
$_POST[note]

$_POST[contact][email]

$_POST[contact][fields][3]
```

I get the first one just fine but I get `ARRAY[EMAIL]` and `ARRAY[FIELDS][3]`

Comment: Please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Comment: Also, you should escape your `$_POST` attributes; i.e. use `$_POST['contact']['email']` or `$_POST["contact"]["email"]` instead of `$_POST[contact][email]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [variable expansion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) incorrectly:

```
$foo = array();
$foo['one']['two'] = 'OK';

echo "Value is $foo[one][two]\n"; // Value is Array[two]
echo "Value is {$foo[one][two]}\n"; // Value is OK
```

... and in the wrong job. Your query should look like this:

```
$sql_note = "INSERT INTO customer_notes(customer_email, note, added_by, note_date)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

... and values should be passed in an array. Injecting raw untrusted data into SQL code is terribly messy to write and leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please check the documentation for your database library.

Comment: Yeah that was my problem! it worked great after adding brackets

Comment: Cool. Just don't forget that you should not be doing it that way. Double-quoted strings have their use cases and this is not one of them.